# Google script Error: Argument must be a range (line 74)

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my function

```
 function Cool() {   var h = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
 var range = 0;   var count = 1;   var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
 "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
 "T"];   for (i = 0; i < 20; i+=0.5) {
     if (i == 19 && count != 5) {
       i == 0;
       count += 1;
     } else if (i == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 || 18) {
       range = h.getSheets()[0].getRange(alph[i] + count + ":" + alph[i] + count);
       SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
       randomize();
     }   } }
```

that has an error on the

```
range = h.getSheets()[0].getRange(alph[i] + count + ":" + alph[i] + count);
```

Comment: `i == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 || 18`? isn't it always true?

Comment: To expand on BlackHatShadow, you are effectively saying `(i == 1) || (2) || (3) ...`, if you know what I mean. If `i` doesn't equal 1, it will hit 2, which will always be converted to true. So you will end up trying to reference `alph[0.5]`, `alph[1.5]` etc which will fail. I think you need `(i == 1) || (i == 2) || (i == 3) ...`, although I'm sure there must be a better way to do what you require.

Comment: Thanks, That worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the data you are using ?

here is a slightly modified version of your script with a logger to see what happens and the log result below. I guess you'll understand why you get error messages . It seems your condition simplified syntax doesn't do what you wanted, does it ?

btw what is the final purpose of this script ? could you explain the idea ?

If you wanted to do something only on integer values of i it would be easier to use something like `if(i==parseInt(i))` for example...

```
function Cool() {   
  var h = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var range = 0;   var count = 1;   var alph = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
 "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
 "T"];   for (i = 0; i < 20; i+=0.5) {
     if (i == 19 && count != 5) {
       i == 0;
       count += 1;
     } else if (i == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 10 || 11 || 12 || 13 || 14 || 15 || 16 || 17 || 18) {
//       range = h.getSheets()[0].getRange(alph[i] + count + ":" + alph[i] + count);
//       SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
 Logger.log('i='+i+'  '+alph[i] + count + ":" + alph[i] + count);
 //      randomize();
     }  
     }
     }
```

**LOGGER RESULT :**

```
i=0  A1:A1
i=0.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=1  B1:B1
i=1.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=2  C1:C1
i=2.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=3  D1:D1
i=3.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=4  E1:E1
i=4.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=5  F1:F1
i=5.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=6  G1:G1
i=6.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=7  H1:H1
i=7.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=8  I1:I1
i=8.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=9  J1:J1
i=9.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=10  K1:K1
i=10.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=11  L1:L1
i=11.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=12  M1:M1
i=12.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=13  N1:N1
i=13.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=14  O1:O1
i=14.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=15  P1:P1
i=15.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=16  Q1:Q1
i=16.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=17  R1:R1
i=17.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=18  S1:S1
i=18.5  undefined1:undefined1
i=19.5  undefined2:undefined2
```

**EDIT :** being *curious by nature* I did try your code with the suggested `IF` statement and I get the following log (much nicer;-) but quite useless, a simple for loop with unity increments would do the same...

```
i=0  A1:A1
i=1  B1:B1
i=2  C1:C1
i=3  D1:D1
i=4  E1:E1
i=5  F1:F1
i=6  G1:G1
i=7  H1:H1
i=8  I1:I1
i=9  J1:J1
i=10  K1:K1
i=11  L1:L1
i=12  M1:M1
i=13  N1:N1
i=14  O1:O1
i=15  P1:P1
i=16  Q1:Q1
i=17  R1:R1
i=18  S1:S1
```

so the question remains : *what was the final goal ?*

Comment: The final goal was to create a random color generator with many different functions. I have alot more functions but i only copied this one.